# Consume a SOAP web service in java

Tags: java, web-services

Consider this class for my web service definition:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Calculator")
    public class Calculator {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "calculate")
    public int[] hello(@WebParam(name = "Value1") int x,@WebParam(name = "Value2") int y) {
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        arr[0] = x + y;
        arr[1] = x - y;
        arr[2] = x * y;
        arr[3] = x / y;
        return arr;
    }
    }
```

How can this simple web service be consumed?
For example, I need to make a simple form that has two inputs and the submit should call this web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Bottom-up approach, means you start with a Java method, and generate the WSDL from it.

if you are using eclipse, to generate WSDL, its simple, New -> Webservice -> Bottom up approach -> select your calculator class (webservice) -> Next - > select methods and finish.

Once its deployed, you can create a new -> webservice client -> select the wsdl and generate it.

or you can use wsimport command :

wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:8888/ws/server?wsdl

Comment: I'm using netbeans
Could you please tell me how to do that in netbeans?

Comment: basically you need to right click on your file and  Choose Generate and Copy WSDL.  
you can follow the steps provided to generate wsdl :
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower_wsdl_schema.html

**OR** 
here :
http://javapapers.com/web-service/soap-web-service-introduction/